# Show dynamic loader when requesting ssr props

Tags: next.js

The problem:
`getServerSideProps` is blocking the whole site on subsequent requests, even when only the props are requested and all other js is already loaded.

So I was wondering if it is possible to add a loading component to each page (something like the dynamic layout: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/layout-component)
and show it instantly while waiting till the props are loaded.

I know about the Router from nextjs and the events but how would I show the loader when I got only the url on `routeChangeStart`?

Comment: Could you not display a loading component based on the URL you're navigating to?

Comment: @juliomalves yes thats what I am currently trying to do, which works not that great on more complicated and dynamic routes.
I am comparing NextJS and AfterJS to see what works better and AfterJS have this feature called instant, so I thought NextJS have it too.

Comment: In Next.js, you'll have to implement the logic yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [getInitialProps](https://nextjs.org/docs/api-reference/data-fetching/getInitialProps) now. Thought it was deprecated, but it's not.

I can now do something like this:

```
const MyPage = (props) => {
    const [data, setData] = useState(null)
    useEffect(() => {
      if (props.data) {
        setData(props.data)
      } else {
        // fetch client side and setData
      }
    });
    return (
      <>
        {data === null && <LoadingMyPage/>}
        {data && <TheActualContent/>}
      </>
    );
}

MyPage.getInitialProps = async () => {
  if (window) return {data: undefined};
  // fetch server side
  return {data: ...}
}
```